# how include embedded Document in rails only query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid3

The model Claim consists of a large number of fields.
In claim controller index action querying claims with the only function, fields that are printed in the index list are querying from the db

```
@claims = @claims.only(:nice_id, :brand_id, etc.. :status).desc(:_id)
```

The class 'Document' embedded in claims, many document embedded in claims.

I need to include documents in the claim to resultant set. what changes are needed to make in my query?

Used Mongoid in place of Active Model,

> mongoid version 3, rails version 3.2

Comment: is Document class AR class if so what kind of association does it have with Claims?

Comment: Claims embeds_many documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for me, on mongoid 3, adding the association name or its alias (`stored_as`) (if any) to `only` works:

```
@claims = @claims.only(:nice_id, :brand_id, ..., :documents).desc(:_id)
```

Comment: In Claim Model `embeds_many :documents, cascade_callbacks: true` and in  Document model  `embedded_in :claim`  i tried this before but this script not working for me